# Java Play! - display formatted JSON

Tags: java, scala, playframework, coffeescript, playframework-2.0

I am trying to display information from a JSON object to a view, following [this tutorial](https://github.com/jamesward/play2torial/blob/master/JAVA.md)

I'd like the JSON to be rendered on a view titled "allBusinesses"

I am able to print the raw JSON to the screen with:

```
    public static Result getBusinesses()
    {
    List<Business> businesses = new Model.Finder(String.class,  Business.class).all();
    return ok(Json.toJson(businesses));  //displays JSON object on empty page
    }
```

then I can render the allBusinesses page with:

```
    public static Result goToAllBusinessesPage()
    {
    return ok(allBusinesses.render());
    }
```

allBusinesses.scala.html looks like:

```
@main("All businesses"){
    <ul id="businesses"></ul>
}
```

And the jQuery/coffeescript reads:

```
$ ->                                            
  $.get "/getBusinesses", (data) ->             
    $.each data, (index, business) ->           
      $("#businesses").append $("<li>").text business.businessName
```

I'd like the javascript to read the JSON getBusinesses() returns and display the business.businessName property to the allBusinesses page

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get javascript to call your server side data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved:

needed to include the javascript in the main.scala.html:

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/index.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```